# Spring Webflux with Kafka Streams Interactive Queries

Tags: reactive-programming, apache-kafka-streams, spring-webflux

I have an in memory state store that I expose via interactive Queries + Rest API.

I am wondering is there an advantage to using the non-blocking Webflux web client to get the key value pairs.

Also I was hoping to use the Web Client between Stream app instances to get the keys that are hosted on remote instances.

What I would like to know is there any benefit to using this or is keyvaluestore.get(key) a blocking call?

Are the client services sending Webflux requests still benefiting?